# Multiple Postgres SELECT processes(django GET requests) stuck, causing 100% CPU usage

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, cpu-usage

I'll try to give as much information I can here. Although the solution would be great, I just want guidance on how to tackle the problem. How to view more useful log files, etc. As I'm new to server maintainance. Any advice are welcome.

Here's what's happenning in chronological order:

- I'm running 2 digitalocean droplets (Ubuntu 14.04 VPS)
- Droplet #1 running django, nginx, gunicorn
- Droplet #2 running postgres
- Everything runs fine for a month and suddenly the postgres droplet
  CPU usage spiked to 100%
- You can see htop log when this happens. I've attached a screenshot
- Another screenshot is nginx error.log, you can see that problem
  started at 15:56:14 where I highlighted with red box
- sudo poweroff the Postgres droplet and restart it doesn't fix the
  problem
- Restore postgres droplet to my last backup (20 hours ago) solves the problem but it keep happening again. This is 7th time in 2 days

I'll continue to do research and give more information. Meanwhile any opinions are welcome.

Thank you.

[image: Postgres server htop log when problem occurs]
[image: nginx error.log when problem occurs]

**Update 20 May 2016**

- Enabled slow query logging on Postgres server as recommended by *e4c5*
- 6 hours later, server freezed(100% CPU usage) again at 8:07 AM. I've attached all related screenshots
- Browser display 502 error if try to access the site during the freeze
- `sudo service restart postgresql` (and gunicorn, nginx on django server) does **NOT** fix
  the freeze (**I think this is a very interesting point**)
- However, restore Postgres server to my previous backup(now 2 days old) **does** fix the freeze
- The culprit **Postgres log** message is **Could not send data to client: Broken
  Pipe**
- The culprit **Nginx log** message is a simple django-rest-framework
  api call which return only 20 items (each with some foreign-key data
  query)

**Update#2 20 May 2016** 
When the freeze occurs, I tried doing the following in chronological order (turn off everything and turn them back on one-by-one)

- `sudo service stop postgresql` --> cpu usage fall to 0-10%
- `sudo service stop gunicorn` --> cpu usage stays at 0-10%
- `sudo service stop nginx`--> cpu usage stays at to 0-10%
- `sudo service restart postgresql` --> cpu usage stays at to 0-10%
- `sudo service restart gunicorn` --> cpu usage stays at to 0-10%
- `sudo service restart nginx` --> **cpu usage rose to 100% and stays
  there**

So this is not about server load or long query time then?

This is very confusing since if I restore database to my latest backup (2 days ago), everything is back online even without touching nginx/gunicorn/django server...

---

Update 8 June 2016
I turned on slow query logging. Set it to log queries that takes longer than 1000ms.

I got this one query shows up in the log many times.

```
SELECT
     "products_product"."id",
     "products_product"."seller_id",
     "products_product"."priority",
     "products_product"."media",
     "products_product"."active",
     "products_product"."title",
     "products_product"."slug",
     "products_product"."description",
     "products_product"."price",
     "products_product"."sale_active",
     "products_product"."sale_price",
     "products_product"."timestamp",
     "products_product"."updated",
     "products_product"."draft",
     "products_product"."hitcount",
     "products_product"."finished",
     "products_product"."is_marang_offline",
     "products_product"."is_seller_beta_program",
     COUNT("products_video"."id") AS "num_video"
 FROM "products_product"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "products_video" ON ( "products_product"."id" = "products_video"."product_id" )
 WHERE ("products_product"."draft" = false AND "products_product"."finished" = true)
 GROUP BY
     "products_product"."id",
     "products_product"."seller_id",
     "products_product"."priority",
     "products_product"."media",
     "products_product"."active",
     "products_product"."title",
     "products_product"."slug",
     "products_product"."description",
     "products_product"."price",
     "products_product"."sale_active",
     "products_product"."sale_price",
     "products_product"."timestamp",
     "products_product"."updated",
     "products_product"."draft",
     "products_product"."hitcount",
     "products_product"."finished",
     "products_product"."is_marang_offline",
     "products_product"."is_seller_beta_program"
 HAVING COUNT("products_video"."id") >= 8
 ORDER BY "products_product"."priority" DESC, "products_product"."hitcount" DESC
 LIMIT 100
```

I know it's such an ugly query (generated by django aggregation). In English, this query just means ***"give me a list of products that have more than 8 videos in it".***

And here the EXPLAIN output of this query:

```
                  QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=351.90..358.40 rows=100 width=933)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=351.90..364.06 rows=187 width=933)
         Filter: (count(products_video.id) >= 8)
         ->  Sort  (cost=351.90..352.37 rows=187 width=933)
               Sort Key: products_product.priority, products_product.hitcount, products_product.id, products_product.seller_id, products_product.media, products_product.active, products_product.title, products_product.slug, products_product.description, products_product.price, products_product.sale_active, products_product.sale_price, products_product."timestamp", products_product.updated, products_product.draft, products_product.finished, products_product.is_marang_offline, products_product.is_seller_beta_program
               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=88.79..344.84 rows=187 width=933)
                     Hash Cond: (products_video.product_id = products_product.id)
                     ->  Seq Scan on products_video  (cost=0.00..245.41 rows=2341 width=8)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=88.26..88.26 rows=42 width=929)
                           ->  Seq Scan on products_product  (cost=0.00..88.26 rows=42 width=929)
                                 Filter: ((NOT draft) AND finished)
```

### (11 rows)

**--- Update 8 June 2016 #2 ---**
Since there are many suggestions by many people. So I'll try to apply the fixes one-by-one and report back periodically.

@e4c5
Here's the information you need:

You can think of my site somewhat like Udemy, an online course marketplace. There are "Product"(course). Each product contain a number of videos. Users can comment on both Product page itself and each Videos.

In many cases, I'll need to query a list of products order by number of TOTAL comments it got(the sum of product comments AND comments on each Video of that Product)

The django query that correspond to the EXPLAIN output above:

```
all_products_exclude_draft = Product.objects.all().filter(draft=False)
products_that_contain_more_than_8_videos =  all_products_exclude_draft.annotate(num_video=Count('video')).filter(finished=True, num_video__gte=8).order_by('timestamp')[:30]
```

I just noticed that I(or some other dev in my team) hit database twice with these 2 python lines.

Here's the django models for Product and Video:

```
from django_model_changes import ChangesMixin

class Product(ChangesMixin, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-priority', '-hitcount']
    seller = models.ForeignKey(SellerAccount)
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    media = models.ImageField(blank=True, 
            null=True, 
            upload_to=download_media_location,
            default=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/images/default_icon.png',
            storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    product_coin_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sale_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sale_price = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True) #100.00
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    hitcount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_marang_offline = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_seller_beta_program = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_avg_rating(self):
        rating_avg = self.productrating_set.aggregate(Avg("rating"), Count("rating"))
        return rating_avg

    def get_total_comment_count(self):
        comment_count = self.video_set.aggregate(Count("comment"))
        comment_count['comment__count'] += self.comment_set.count()
        return comment_count

    def get_total_hitcount(self):
        amount = self.hitcount
        for video in self.video_set.all():
            amount += video.hitcount
        return amount

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        view_name = "products:detail_slug"
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def get_product_share_link(self):
        full_url = "%s%s" %(settings.FULL_DOMAIN_NAME, self.get_absolute_url())
        return full_url

    def get_edit_url(self):
        view_name = "sellers:product_edit"
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs={"pk": self.id})

    def get_video_list_url(self):
        view_name = "sellers:video_list"
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs={"pk": self.id})

    def get_product_delete_url(self):
        view_name = "products:product_delete"
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs={"pk": self.id})

    @property
    def get_price(self):
        if self.sale_price and self.sale_active:
            return self.sale_price
        return self.product_coin_price

    @property
    def video_count(self):
        videoCount = self.video_set.count()
        return videoCount

class Video(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(SellerAccount)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    story = models.TextField(default=" ")
    chapter_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    hitcount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    objects = VideoManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'product')
        ordering = ['chapter_number', 'timestamp']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_comment_count(self):
        comment_count = self.comment_set.all_jing_jing().count()
        return comment_count

    def get_create_chapter_url(self):
        return reverse("sellers:video_create", kwargs={"pk": self.id})

    def get_edit_url(self):
        view_name = "sellers:video_update"
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs={"pk": self.id})

    def get_video_delete_url(self):
        view_name = "products:video_delete"
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs={"pk": self.id})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        try:
            return reverse("products:video_detail", kwargs={"product_slug": self.product.slug, "pk": self.id})
        except:
            return "/"

    def get_video_share_link(self):
        full_url = "%s%s" %(settings.FULL_DOMAIN_NAME, self.get_absolute_url())
        return full_url      

    def get_next_url(self):
        current_product = self.product
        videos = current_product.video_set.all().filter(chapter_number__gt=self.chapter_number)
        next_vid = None
        if len(videos) >= 1:
            try:
                next_vid = videos[0].get_absolute_url()
            except IndexError:
                next_vid = None
        return next_vid

    def get_previous_url(self):
        current_product = self.product
        videos = current_product.video_set.all().filter(chapter_number__lt=self.chapter_number).reverse()
        next_vid = None
        if len(videos) >= 1:
            try:
                next_vid = videos[0].get_absolute_url()
            except IndexError:
                next_vid = None
        return next_vid
```

And here is the index of the Product and Video table I got from the command:

```
my_database_name=# \di
```

Note: this is photoshopped and include some other models as well.
[image: Indexes of Product and Video models]

---

**--- Update 8 June 2016 #3 ---**
@Jerzyk
As you suspected. After I inspect all my code again, I found that I indeed did a 'slicing-in-memory': I tried to shuffle the first 10 results by doing this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        all_product_list = Product.objects.all().filter(draft=False).annotate(
        num_video=Count(
                Case(
                    When(
                        video__draft=False,
                        then=1,
                    )
                )
            )
        ).order_by('-priority', '-num_video', '-hitcount')
        the_first_10_products = list(all_product_list[:10])
        the_11th_product_onwards = list(all_product_list[10:])
        random.shuffle(copy)
        finalList = the_first_10_products + the_11th_product_onwards
```

Note: in the code above I need to count number of Video that is not in draft status.

So this will be one of the thing I need to fix as well. Thanks. >_<

---

--- Here are the related screenshots ---

*Postgres log when freezing occurs (log_min_duration = 500 milliseconds)*
[image: Postgres log 20 May 2016]

*Postgres log (contunued from the above screenshot)*
[image: Postgres log 20 May 2016 (page2)]

*Nginx error.log in the same time period*
[image: Nginx log 20 May 2016]

*DigitalOcean CPU usage graph just before freezing*
[image: DigitalOcean graph 20 May 2016 (1)]

*DigitalOcean CPU usage graph just after freezing*
[image: DigitalOcean graph 20 May 2016 (2)]

Comment: enable slow query log (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html see log_min_duration) and see what shows up. Looks like you have a succession of slow queries hitting one after another if that happens resulting IO waits will lead to time outs

Comment: First step would be to **lower** the number of concurrent sessions on the postgres server. That will probably give it some air. (and the probable cause is a bad data model)

Comment: Thank you both for information. I'll try enabling slow query log and report back what I found.

Comment: Update : Followed your advice by enabling slow query log, I've edited the question, added a lot more new information about today's crash. I'm looking into what might cause 'Broken Pipe' now

Comment: @joop I also just changed max_connections (in postgresql.conf) to 50 from the default 100. If this is what you mean by lowering the number of concurrent sessions. I'll report back if it still freeze.

Comment: Before the freeze, your queries are taking several seconds to run, and right after, they only take half a second. As if there is a build-up to the freeze.

Comment: @Kakyoin : that was my intention. [do note that this is only temporal; fewer processes := fewer waiting processes] The broken-pipes could be caused by application or network timeouts. IMHO, the real problem is still bad database design (missing FKs, PKs, indexes).

Comment: @joop Update: max_connections = 50 doesn't help as expected. I just got another freeze. About the database design, my data is a django models for a novel reader/writer marketplace. (Author, Novel title, story, comments, etc) I'll post the django model later if it helps.

Comment: Update : I edited the question. Providing more info about turning everything off, then back on one-by-one. CPU then spiked to 100% as soon as I turned nginx on.

Comment: now, as you have it up and running use django-debug-toolbar to check how many queries are you sending, the top 3 mistakes are: loading all result to the db and then slicing, using related objects without select_related causing cascade queries, not using indexes on the data

Comment: The issue occur again today. I'll try  django-debug-toolbar and will report what I found. T_T

Comment: Sure. I'll get those queries Explained and analyzed. Trying to copy the text out of the terminal. Will post them once ready.

Comment: You said that restoring from a backup helps. Have you tried taking DB dump after the slowdown (stop postgres, stop nginx, start postgres, do pg_dump) and comparing it to a backed-up dump? Maybe something will pop up.

Comment: @e4c5 I updated the question with the slow query and its EXPLAIN output. Now I'm working on understanding it. ;)

Comment: @Jerzyk Still can't get django-debug-toolbar to work on my vagrant machine. Still working on it. By the way, one of my friends mention about using index as well. So I'm going to try adding index to see if it helps. Will report what I found.

Comment: @Roman Than makes sense. I'll try that if adding index doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: @Jerzyk I'm interested in the top 3 mistakes you mentioned. I've looked up how to use select_related in django. I'm trying indexing as well. But I don't understand what do you mean by "loading all result to the db and then slicing"?

Comment: @Kakyoin select_related, then prefetch_related (sometimes needed), then loading "to the memory" (sorry for my mistake) eg: list(User.object.all())[20:30] instead User.objects.all()[20:30] which will be sliced on the DB level or more obvious: len(User.objects.all()) instead of User.objects.count()
if you wil manage to run djdt you will see how much time each query takes  so you can check if you are missing indexes or not

Comment: @Kakyoin be carefull with creation of indexes - you need to first understand where you really need it

Comment: I think we have almost all the information needed. One last thing we need is the products model and the indexes on that table.

Comment: @e4c5 I've updated the question with Product and Video models, indexes and the django query. I'm looking into caching the result.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: why do you use screenshots? Whatever terminal emulator you use, it sure has a copy-pasting capability.

Comment: @Roman In some cases, I need to censored some information and it's easier =) I will post the code instead of screenshots where possible.

Comment: @Jerzyk I indeed did some 'slicing-in-memory' as you suspected. I edited the question to add this information and put this on my fix-list.

Comment: you have an index like this:  unique_together = ('slug', 'product') when making this, did you drop the default index on `product`? Can you update your question one more time giving the full indexes that exists on your table.

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for quick reply. I'm typing this on a phone so I'll provide more information later. The truth is I have never create/use/drop any index at all. This is my first time working with a database server and I let django handle everything. And sorry for asking this but how do I get you the 'full indexes that exists on my table'? I thought "\di" command should display all the indexes?

Comment: You can find the indexes by clicking on the table in PGadmin. If no one has created or dropped any indexes manually, we can get a pretty good idea about the indexes from the table.

Comment: That's for adding some of the indexes. It would be better if you could type `\d products_product` because that would actually show what columns are being indexed as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can jump to the conclusion that your problems are caused by the slow query in question. By itself each run of the query does not appear to be slow enough to cause timeouts. However it's possible several of these queries are executed concurrently and that could lead to the meltdown. There are two things that you can do to speed things up.

### 1) Cache the result

The result of a long running query can be cached.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def get_8x_videos():
    cache_key = 'products_videos_join'
    result = cache.get(cache_key, None)
    if not result:
        all_products_exclude_draft = Product.objects.all().filter(draft=False)
        result =  all_products_exclude_draft.annotate(num_video=Count('video')).filter(finished=True, num_video__gte=8).order_by('timestamp')[:30]

        result = Product.objects.annotate('YOUR LONG QUERY HERE')
        cache.set(cache_key, result)

    return result
```

This query now comes from memcache (or whatever you use for caching) that means if you have two successive hits for the page that uses this in quick succession, the second one will have no impact on the database. You can control how long the object is cached in memory.

### 2) Optimize the Query

The first thing that leaps out at you from the explain is that you are doing sequential scan on both the `products_products` and `product_videos` tables. Usually sequential scans are less desirable than index scans. However an index scan *may not* be used on this query because of the `COUNT()` and `HAVING` `COUNT()` clauses you have on it as well as the massive `GROUP BY` clauses on it.

update:

Your query has a LEFT OUTER JOIN, It's possible that an INNER JOIN or a subquery might be faster, in order to do that, we need to recognize that grouping on the `Video` table on `product_id` can give us the set of videos that figure in at least 8 products.

```
inner = RawSQL('SELECT id from product_videos GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(product_id) > 1',params=[])

Product.objects.filter(id__in=b)
```

The above eleminates the LEFT OUTER JOIN and introduces a subquery. However this doesn't give easy access to the actual number of videos for each product, so this query in it's present form may not be fully usable.

### 3) Improving indexes

While it may be tempting to create an index on `draft` and `finished` columns, this will be futile as those columns do not have sufficient cardinality to be good candidates for indexes. However it may still be possible to create a conditional index. Again the conclusion can only be drawn after seeing your tables.

Comment: I have updated my answer by making the caching function a concrete implementation. Please do try this , it will lead to a big boost in performance.

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. Can't wait to try this. I'll be able to start  implementing this tomorrow evening. This should make this query disappear from the slow-query-log. I'll report back what I found. If things run fine for some time then I'll mark this as answer. :)  (just in case there's other culprit bugs still lurking around...) I'd like to thank everyone for your inputs as well. I've learned a lot from this thread. =)

Comment: Updated my answer by showing how a subquery maybe used

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Things seem to run fine now. I've accepted this as answer and also awarded the bounty. In fact, I'd like to accept everyone's comments as answers. Because it all helps with server stability. I'll need to continue to implement everything you all suggests over time to ensure my Postgres server won't go down again. Anyway, thanks for now. =)

Comment: Really happy to have helped. Thank you for the bounty! Since you can't upvote your own answer, let me do the honours

Answer (score 3):

*** Update 7 June 2016 : Issue occur again. CPU hit 100% and stays there. This answer does help with performance but unfortunately not the solution to this problem.

---

Thanks to the recommendation by DigitalOcean suppport team. I tried the configuration suggested by this tool:

http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/

Which recommend me the following values for my droplet with 1 CPU core and 1GB RAM:

in postgresql.conf:

```
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 256MB
effective_cache_size = 768MB
work_mem = 1310kB
maintenance_work_mem = 64MB
checkpoint_segments = 32
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 7864kB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
kernel.shmmax=536870912
kernel.shmall=131072
```

Until now my postgres server has been running fine for 3-4 days. So I assume this is the solution. Thanks everyone!